# SQL Server: Optimizer intelligence with multiple indexes on the same table in a UNION ALL query

Tags: t-sql, optimization, indexing, database-performance

I'm trying to write a query for a rather large table (10 million+ would be a typical size), the result of which needs to be filtered on various predicates / conditions based on some business logic. My question: does the query optimizier (in SQL Server 2008+) attempt to use a single index for the whole query, or does it attempt to use different indexes on a by-query basis?

Consider the following:

```
--Use Index A
SELECT Set1 
FROM ATable
WHERE AColumn = sarg-able value

UNION ALL

--Are we stuck with Index A?
SELECT Set2 
FROM ATable
WHERE BColumn = sarg-able value
```

If we choose Index A for Set1, are we stuck with Index A for the entire query, or is the optimizer smart enough to use a *different* index for Set2 (assuming one exists)?

Comment: The query optimizer will use any indexes that ought to improve the performance in its little virtual mind. That means it may choose to use a [covering index](http://www.dbadiaries.com/sql-server-covering-index-and-key-lookup/) rather than a simple index on `AColumn`. It's also possible that updating index statistics will change the execution plan (when the query is recompiled), e.g. if an index becomes more or less selective. (An index with 50,000 distinct values for 1,000,000 rows is more selective than one with 10 distinct values. Or 1.)

Answer (score 2):

Everything @andreyNikolov said is 100% correct. This is the kind of thing you can easily figure out on your own by reviewing the *Actual Execution Plan* (Not *Estimated* Execution plan). Note the following sample data, table and index structure:

```
USE tempdb -- safe place in Dev to test this kind of thing...
GO

-- sample data and indexes
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.ATable','U') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE dbo.ATable
CREATE TABLE dbo.ATable
(
  Set1    INT NOT NULL,
  Set2    INT NOT NULL,
  AColumn INT NOT NULL,
  BColumn INT NOT NULL
);

INSERT dbo.ATable (Set1, Set2, AColumn, BColumn)
VALUES (1,2,3,3),(1,2,4,4),(5,5,6,6),(11,22,40,40),(11,20,40,44),(11,22,14,4),(1,2,3,3);

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX indexA ON dbo.ATable(AColumn) INCLUDE(Set1);
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX indexB ON dbo.ATable(BColumn) INCLUDE(Set2);
```

Now run the following with "Include Actual Execution Plan" turned on.

```
SELECT Set1 --Use Index A
FROM   dbo.ATable
WHERE  AColumn = 3
UNION ALL
SELECT Set2 --Use Index B
FROM   dbo.ATable
WHERE BColumn = 4;
```

... and the execution plan:

[image]

The query above the UNION ALL performs a *nonclustered **seek*** against IndexA's key column (AColumn). Because I included Set1 as an include column on IndexA, IndexA can satisfy the query without a Rid or Key lookup against. This is how indexes should be designed. The same is true about the query below the UNION ALL except that it's using IndexB.

Again, this is the kind of thing that is easy to figure out on your own once you have a full understanding of how to read the execution plans.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the optimizer is smart enough. These are two separate operations, which can be performed either as a table/index scans or seeks. The decision for executing each one of them is independent and it is perfectly normal to use different indexes for each of them. Then the results of both operations will be combined.